# Progress bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar, gsap

I have some problems with my simple scroll indicator component.

when I reduce the window, scrolls down and I enlarge the window the the initial value is higher.

And I don't know is this a good solution in this case (performance): gsap.ticker.add(tickHandler)

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-golick-zb6t1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: [Cross post on the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/23607-smoothing-out-progress-on-scroll-resize/) where it has been answered.

Answer (score -2):

Try using CSS styling to build your custom scrollbar: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.